# Drive API returns 400 response with INVALID VALUE at pageToken

Tags: python, mysql, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I have deployed a code to read data from a drive folder. I store the last called pagetoken in SQL and run it in a loop to retrieve data for all items in the folder(>250k).
The loop works in 2 ways, either it starts from the beginning and calls the nextPageToken iteratively or it uses the last nextPageToken value saved in my sql table to run the same loop.

When I use the token without calling from SQL, it works perfectly till all the data is read, but when called with SQL, it returns a bad request error. This process worked perfectly till I hadn't filtered my request by a modified time value.

```
def get_video_items(folder, service, token=None, begin=None, to=None):
    # EXTRACT ALL ITEMS FROM SPECIFIED FOLDER
    if not token:
        size = PAGESIZE_2
        response = service.files().list(q="'" + folder[0]['id'] + "' in parents and modifiedTime > '" + begin + "'and"
                                        "modifiedTime < '" + to + "'",
                                        orderBy='modifiedTime asc',
                                        pageSize=size, fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name, webViewLink)').execute()

    else:
        size = PAGESIZE_2
        response = service.files().list(q="'" + folder[0]['id'] + "' in parents and modifiedTime > '" + begin + "'and"
                                        "modifiedTime < '" + to + "'",
                                        orderBy='modifiedTime asc',
                                        pageSize=size, fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name, webViewLink)',
                                        pageToken=token).execute()

    videos = response.get('files', [])
    # RECORD PAGE TOKEN TO CALL NEXT PAGE
    if len(videos) < size:
        videos = None
    else:
        token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
    return videos, token
```

The error I receive is the following

> raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting [https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=************+in+parents+and+modifiedTime+%3E+%272019-07-01T16%3A48%3A13.212522%27andmodifiedTime+%3C+%272022-07-01T10%3A38%3A13.212491%27&orderBy=modifiedTime+asc&pageSize=50&fields=nextPageToken%2C+files%28id%2C+name%2C+webViewLink%29&pageToken=~%21%21~AI9FV7Qu_zWbHy0zBnPqDegUffr0l2XrKvi_U_M8W17yWJ59skMILpiAR-0Oc_i-ZDxrj8Jx3AXBaMrqUh9fnrtxDcBEn4qKTHsdm4Y4_rnc6SJItgaXmOfx7HVjszfmG5z-bOHU-7flG0EIP1a2HIXq-GWFffu2ykGUaDACnteguHEjAe-tNEmPnRR1tHNmNEJACFgWnTnoCXb0w2M9kjA_VXGLwMtQ1Ar-Y9A6IJH3wQXxrIqVrIlWfJ-cEu0z6zGv3saM942Y4O0SKzLyTXk8-SWIozKH5pcFfeBTtn1z_OySgl-lHNIxRgu77lRy9wmgBhCAki8GHL0YjB_QXq7sodq7uwc9VPadokI7__0uoDCjAnvPkQ7gjH7VQWI80a1DadQ0GrZ3&alt=json](https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=************+in+parents+and+modifiedTime+%3E+%272019-07-01T16%3A48%3A13.212522%27andmodifiedTime+%3C+%272022-07-01T10%3A38%3A13.212491%27&orderBy=modifiedTime+asc&pageSize=50&fields=nextPageToken%2C+files%28id%2C+name%2C+webViewLink%29&pageToken=%7E%21%21%7EAI9FV7Qu_zWbHy0zBnPqDegUffr0l2XrKvi_U_M8W17yWJ59skMILpiAR-0Oc_i-ZDxrj8Jx3AXBaMrqUh9fnrtxDcBEn4qKTHsdm4Y4_rnc6SJItgaXmOfx7HVjszfmG5z-bOHU-7flG0EIP1a2HIXq-GWFffu2ykGUaDACnteguHEjAe-tNEmPnRR1tHNmNEJACFgWnTnoCXb0w2M9kjA_VXGLwMtQ1Ar-Y9A6IJH3wQXxrIqVrIlWfJ-cEu0z6zGv3saM942Y4O0SKzLyTXk8-SWIozKH5pcFfeBTtn1z_OySgl-lHNIxRgu77lRy9wmgBhCAki8GHL0YjB_QXq7sodq7uwc9VPadokI7__0uoDCjAnvPkQ7gjH7VQWI80a1DadQ0GrZ3&alt=json) returned "Invalid Value". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'invalid', 'message': 'Invalid Value', 'locationType': 'parameter', 'location': 'pageToken'}]"

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Also, could this be because the 'to' value in my code and hence the query changes? If so, how can I handle it, having the 'begin' value be the same always.

Comment: Have you checked on how the sql call returns the value? Is it the same as the one received without calling from SQL?

Comment: Why are you saving the pagetoken?  its going to expire you know

Comment: @Kessy, SQL returns the right value, no issues there.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a request to google in this instance to make a [file.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) request.  Google crunches data determines how many rows are to be returned based upon pageSize either sent by you or they use the default.

If the total number of rows to be returned is greater than the pageSize, then they add a nextpagetoken for you to use.  Next page means exactly that it returns the next page of data.  Not page number 2 of data, its the next page of data returned from the total of your request.

So you then make another request this time including the nextpage token which will return page 2 of data. If again the total number of rows is greater than the pageSize a new nextpagetoken is added to the request for you to use to get the next page.   This time page 3.

You can not reuse a next page token because it was already used, you need to use the new next page token. To get page three, google assumes that you have already stored page twos data.  That token will no longer work.

Im not sure why you would bother storing these. Next page tokens expire, very fast the server doesn't store your request indefinitely after all.  This is a use it or lose it type of thing.

- NextPageTokens can only be used once
- NextPageTokens are short lived.

Comment: So, I'm actually using the nextPageToken in the function arg 'token'. As for short lived, the code runs for a while and ends within a single while loop, so the tokens won't really expire.

Comment: Like I said in my comment, I think the issue lies in the change of end date. I was using pagetokens because at the end of my code, I'm retrieving the data only if the length of data is as big as the pagesize value i've ascertained, if not we wait for a while and continue again till the page is completely full.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The issue, like I suspected lay in changing the end date of the query.

To fix this, I added a method where I saved a "done till" value, which in turn was used in the next query to filter with dates. As for the page tokens, they are being used only till all results within each query are read, after which the completion timestamp is saved and is used for the query in the next run with a new end timestamp, which in turn becomes the start time for the run after that.

It's only weird to me that the end time being changed on a query, with the same start time leads to a new page token system and makes the old one useless.